# False dateresult using date() php

Tags: php, parsing, date, strtotime

I want to parse the date `1938` `1938+02:00` using `date()` & `strtotime()`.

My code:

```
echo date("Y", strtotime("1938+02:00"));
```

gives me as result "2014"..

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is `1938+02:00` anyway? 2am january 1st 1938?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For something like this just get the first four characters of the string. No need to work with dates and such:

```
echo substr('1938+02:00', 0, 4);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/215189)

But if you insist on using date functionality you'll need to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` as that date string is not a standard format.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YP', '1938+02:00');
echo $date->format('Y');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/215188)

Comment: op wants to use date() & strtotime(),I didn't downvote

Comment: actually my first thought is to escape that plus sign lol. there is a correct format after all. +1

Comment: *"Downvoter care to explain?"* - Exactly. Well, I compensated for it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you, sir. It was a quick downvote which makes me question their real intention.

Comment: You're welcome John. You are by far a person who has mastered the concept of time. Just don't be late for a date ;) *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I only hope to be late for my own funeral ;)

Answer (score 0):

`date("Y");` only return the year. That's what the `Y` does.

See the Manual page for [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for other options.

**EDIT**

Another thing to consider, is that timestamps only go back to 1970. That's what a timestamp is (the number of seconds since 1970).

So, that's going to give you a negative value for the timestamp.

Comment: I want only the Year.

Comment: Then what's the problem?

Comment: it returns 2014 not 1938?

Comment: @Elias35 ah, just noticed, see my updae.

Comment: by the way i can't change the dateformat because i take this information from a api.

Answer (score -1):

Your date string is not in an acceptable format. [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) is a list of acceptable formats for `strtotime`

Comment: This is correct, but you should also show how to work with that date format. Otherwise this answer isn't very helpful.